# M2 - Reset Salable Quantity

Tags: stock, quantity

Is it possible to reset the Salable Quantity? It looks like our Stock and Salable Quantity is going the wrong way, they show to much difference. It can because of we removed all the test orders...

So we need to reset it so we can make a fresh start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already found it, just had to truncate the table "inventory_reservation".